# How to describe the data structure of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I am looking for a way describe the data structure (not the data itself) of a data frame in R.

```
df = read.csv2('data.csv')
desc(df)
```

Output should be like

```
 df.columnname1
 df.columnname2 (type)
 ...
```

Comment: Have you tried running str(df)? Is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: `summary.default(df)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail That is the answer. Please transform it to an answer.

Comment: @mkt: Very nice, too. But it touches data in the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df_types <- data.frame("col_types" = unlist(lapply(df, typeof)))
```

I use `lapply` to loop over columns getting their type. This output is a named list, so I then use `unlist` to convert into a named character vector and cast this to a `data.frame` to get the printed output in the format that you're after.